# How to validate dropdown in asp.net mvc2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc 2.0.I have to validate my dropdownlist after clicking save button.
this is my view code.

```
 <%using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Save" }))
      {
    %>
    <table>
                       <tr>
                       <td>
                            <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeName)%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>
                            <%:Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectModel, new SelectList(Model.ProjectModel, "Id", "ProjectName"), new { @id = "ddlProject"})%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <center>
                    <div id="result">
                        <%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViews/partialpage.ascx");>
                    </div>
                </center>
    </table>
    <%} %>
```

and my java script code is:

```
      $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {

                $.ajax(
                {
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $('#Save').attr('action'),
                    data: $('#Save').serialize(),

                    success: function (data) {
                          $('#result').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                    }
                });
              });
        });
```

here am using

```
       input type="button"
```

because i have to return partial view after submit save button.

can anyone tell how to validate my dropdown??

Comment: please, write elementary javascript code for postback when button clicked. perhaps this accour difference beetween input submit and input button. Submit use behavery submit fuction, but input button doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I write this as follow in **Asp.Net Mvc4**.  I think that perhaps it is same in Mvc2.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Contract.ContractStatusId, new SelectList(Model.ContractStatus, "ContractStatusId", "Name"), "--  Select Status --", new { data_form = "select2", @style = "width: 200px;" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contract.ContractStatusId)
```

Comment: :that one i tried,but it worked only for input type=submit not  input type=button